# Implement AWS Lambda Pre/Post Traffic Hook Using C#

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-code-deploy

I needed to implement a lambda pre and post traffic hook using C#.  I couldn't find any good examples of how to do this in C# but I was able to figure it out.

Here is a sample of how I was able to get it to work:

```
using Amazon.CodeDeploy.Model;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Amazon.Lambda.Core;
using System;

namespace xxxxx.LambdaFunctions
{
    [LambdaSerializer(typeof(Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json.JsonSerializer))]
    public async Task FunctionHandler(PutLifecycleEventHookExecutionStatusRequest status, ILambdaContext context)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(status);

        LambdaLogger.Log("Processing lifecycle pre-traffic hook.");

        Amazon.CodeDeploy.LifecycleEventStatus? eventStatus = Amazon.CodeDeploy.LifecycleEventStatus.Failed;

        try
        {
            // Perform your pre/post traffic hook tests here

            eventStatus = Amazon.CodeDeploy.LifecycleEventStatus.Succeeded;
        }
        catch (InvalidStatusCodeException exc)
        {
            eventStatus = Amazon.CodeDeploy.LifecycleEventStatus.Failed;
            LambdaLogger.Log($"PreTrafficHook failed with status code {exc.StatusCode}.");
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            eventStatus = Amazon.CodeDeploy.LifecycleEventStatus.Failed;
            LambdaLogger.Log($"Error: {exc.Message}");
        }
        finally
        {
            using var codedeploy = new Amazon.CodeDeploy.AmazonCodeDeployClient();

            var request = new PutLifecycleEventHookExecutionStatusRequest()
            {
                DeploymentId = status.DeploymentId,
                LifecycleEventHookExecutionId = status.LifecycleEventHookExecutionId,
                Status = eventStatus,
            };

            await codedeploy.PutLifecycleEventHookExecutionStatusAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is a pre and post traffic hook? What traffic does this pertain to?

Comment: Pre and post traffic hooks allow you to verify your lambda is working during deployment and the transition to your new lambda version.  See this article:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/tutorial-lambda-sam-create-lambda-before-traffic.html

Comment: Ah OK, so it's a CodeDeploy feature.